# Laravel update multiple database rows with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to update the products leased count when a product is rented to a customer. 
The owner of the website can rent multiple things. I do this by cloning with Ajax.

Now, when someone has rented like 2 chairs and 1 table, i want to update the products_leased row for both products. How would i do that?

**The error i get:**

```
`SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'product_leased' at row 1 (SQL: update `products` set `product_leased` = 3 5, `updated_at` = 2017-06-07 19:57:03 where `id` = 1)`
```

**My controller:**

```
public function create_order($id) {

    $customer = Customer::find($id);
    $pr = Product::get();

    $rent_from = Request::input('rent_from');
    $rent_till = Request::input('rent_till');
    $productArray = Request::get('product_name');
    $productCountArray = Request::get('product_count');

    $rentProduct = new cRent;
    $rentProduct->customer_id = $customer->id;
    $rentProduct->rent_from = $rent_from;
    $rentProduct->rent_till = $rent_till;
    $rentProduct->rented_products = implode(', ', $productArray);
    $rentProduct->rented_products_count = implode(', ', $productCountArray);

    $rentProduct->save();

    $pru = Product::find($id);

    $pru->product_leased = implode(' ', $productCountArray);
    $pru->update();

    return back();


}
```

The code above works only when one product has been rented. Not when i rent 2 products.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you give us little bit idea about database table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you passing in the same $id to

```
 $customer = Customer::find($id);
```

and

```
$pru = Product::find($id);
```

?

Instead of imploding the product names and counts and storing them together, why not create separate rent records for each product and relate them as a one-to-many? Assuming product name and product count line in the arrays, something to the effect of:

```
foreach(array_combine($productArray, $productCountArray) as $product_name => $count){
    $product = Product::where('name', $product_name)->first();
    $rentProduct = new cRent;
    $rentProduct->customer_id = $customer->id;
    $rentProduct->rent_from = $rent_from;
    $rentProduct->rent_till = $rent_till;
    $rentProduct->product_id = $product->id
    $rentProduct->count = $count;
    $rentProduct->save();
}
```

Better yet, don't pass in the product names, instead pass the product ids in from the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rentProduct = new cRent;
```

the code above indicates only one instance of your cRent off-course if you want have another transaction with the database with a different values or data another instance is needed

I think what you want is something like this

```
public function create_order($id) {

    $customer = Customer::find($id);
    $pr = Product::get();

    $rent_from = Request::input('rent_from');
    $rent_till = Request::input('rent_till');
    $productArray = Request::get('product_name');
    $productCountArray = Request::get('product_count');

    foreache($productArray as $prod){

        $rentProduct = new cRent;
        $rentProduct->customer_id = $customer->id;
        $rentProduct->rent_from = $rent_from;
        $rentProduct->rent_till = $rent_till;
        $rentProduct->rented_products = $prod
        $rentProduct->rented_products_count = //not sure in this line

        $rentProduct->save();
    }



    $pru = Product::find($id);

    $pru->product_leased = implode(' ', $productCountArray);
    $pru->update();

    return back();


}
```